# Связь моделей в Джанго

Tags: python, django, django-model

Есть 2 класса в Джанго
Класс команды с помощью которого я записываю все команды в базу данных

Класс матч который будет содержать ссылку и название играющих команд
Вопрос в следующем, как мне создавая матч используя Shell в переменные team1 и team2 записать команды играющие? и в последующем выводить имена этих команд?
Что бы получить условно в базе следующее

id1 team1=Spartak team2=Lokomotiv link= ....

id2 team2=Zenit team2= CSKA link= ....

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    league = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Match(models.Model):
    team1 = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Team1')
    team2 = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Team2')
    link = models.URLField
    time = models.DateTimeField

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то тебе нужно

```
   spartak = Team.objects.get(name='Спартак') # или если имена не уникальные, а знаешь id, тогда Team.objects.get(pk=id_spartak)
   lokomotiv = Team.objects.get(name='Локомотив') 
   Match.objects.create(team1=spartak, team2=lokomotiv, link=..., time=...)
```

аналогично с другими матчами
если будешь выполнять в shell не забудь импортировать Teamp, Match

Comment: А в результате в базе данных будет что хранится в переменных team1 и team2 ? айдишка команд или название просто?  или зависит от того что я туда кладу?

Comment: Попробовал сделать это, в итоге в базе данных хранятся айдишки команд а мне бы как то нужно их имена хранить что бы потом выводить их на html на странице. То есть что бы по итогу в team1 / team2 были не id 1 и 2 просто а название самих команд. team1= Спартак team2= Иска

Comment: В базе будут храниться именно id и это нормально. Если ты захочешь вывести имена команд, то можно будет сделать match.team1 (так как у тебя определен __str__ rкак self.name у модели team), то вывод будет именно имени. Либо можно match.team1.name